# Accessing PHP Object variables with the same name?

Tags: php, arrays, object

Apologies for the poor terminology, can't think of the right words to describe this issue so this example should be of more use.

I'm polling an API server and returning back a JSON object that I've used json_decode to turn into a PHP object.

An example of the returned result in xml format is here: http://balifoodsafari.com.au/RGJ4QHE.xml

In this result there are multiple field subsets under booking->fields each with it's own label and value. I need to process through these and assign the right field value to the right variable and I can't guarantee the fields will be in the same order each time I poll the API server.

My thought as I'm writing this would be something like:

```
foreach($decoded->booking->fields->field as $field){
   if($field->label == "Name of Hotel / Accommodation"){
       $hotelname = $field->value;
   }
   elseif(){repeat for 2nd field name}
   elseif(){repeat for 3rd field name}
   elseif(){repeat for 4th field name}
}
```

Basically, foreach field found run a series of checks to find the matching field label and match up the variable. Is there a better way to do this and/or will the code above work?

Answer (score 0):

How about, instead of assigning to variables, you use an associative array instead?

```
$fieldNames = array(
  'Name of Hotel / Accommodation' => 'hotelname',
  // ...
);

$fields = array();

foreach($decoded->booking->fields->field as $field){
    if (isset($fieldNames($field->label)) {
        $fields[$fieldNames[$field->label]] = $field->value;
    }
}

// $fields will be something like array('hotelname' => '...', ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is better to use a switch case statement like this

```
switch($field->label) {
    case "fieldLabel1":
        //First if cond
        break;
    case "fieldLabel2":
        //2nd if cond
        break;
    case "fieldLabel3":
        //third if cond
        break;
    case "fieldLabel4":
        //fourth cond
        break;
    default:
        //else cond
}
```

because compiler is better in optimizing a switch-statement than an if-statement. In case of if-else statements the compiler doesn't know if the order of evaluating the if-statements is important to you, and can't perform any optimizations there. You could be calling methods in the if-statements, influencing variables. With the switch-statement it knows that all clauses can be evaluated at the same time and can put them in whatever order is most efficient.

[Comparison between switch and if else](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SpeedTestIfElseSwitch.aspx)

Comment: Does OP have performance issues? While there's nothing wrong with a `switch` statement, your argumentation sounds so much like [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).